# Unity: Why does playModeStateChanged get called after Start?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this:

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += x => { PlaymodeStateChanged(); };
    }

    private static void PlaymodeStateChanged()
    {
        Debug.Log("Play mode changed");
    }
}
```

and another class with a `Debug.Log("Start()");` in the Start method.
When I hit play I see on the log output:
`Start()`
`Play mode changed`

Shouldn't `playModeStateChanged` get called *before* `Start` is called on all objects? Any way to go around this? I need this so I can initialize an object before other objects that need to reference this one run Start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess based on the docs:

> **EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged**
>
> Add an event handler to this event to receive a notification that the play mode state *has changed*

Note the use of past tense - this event promises to notify you only *after* the state has changed. It's not a `playModeStateWillChange` event.

But clearly your static constructor is getting called earlier, thanks to the `[InitializeOnLoad]` attribute:

> Note that static constructors with this attribute are called when Unity starts and *when Run is pressed*. In this second case the Unity runtime is intialised and this is treated as a Load.

So it looks like, rather than registering to handle the event after the editor finishes starting playmode (which apparently includes calling `Start()` for all `MonoBehaviours` in the open scenes), you could act immediately in the static constructor.

Since this constructor also fires when the editor loads, you might need to check:

> **EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode**
>
> Is editor either currently in play mode, or about to switch to it? (Read Only)
>
> This will return true when editor will switch to play mode after finishing some tasks (e.g. after scripts will be recompiled).

to verify whether this initialization is due to the editor loading or a play mode switch.

Give that a shot, and let us know if that helps you get your needed actions in before `Start()` happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply DMGregory. I tried your solution and I'm getting closer to solving this. I'm using PlayModeStateChanged to spawn a gameobject and it gives me this error: `Some objects were not cleaned up when closing the scene. (Did you spawn new GameObjects from OnDestroy?)` so I guess I cant spawn stuff from there. Do you happen to know if there is a way to know if Awake is running/has ran?

Comment: I just found out about UnityEditor.Callbacks.PostProcessSceneAttribute. I'm using it to instantiate my object. I am aware that it wont work on a build, but for me this isn't a problem since I only need this in the editor. You put me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: @ItsaMeTuni That sounds like a better solution than what I proposed above. I recommend writing that up as an answer and (after the short waiting period) marking it as the accepted answer.